# how to make vim automatically open .js as compiled .coffee and save back to .js

Tags: javascript, vim, compiler-construction, coffeescript

I've found how to compile js to coffe on write, but not how to compile js to coffe on read. Strikes me this might be awesome.

Is this possible or is there perhaps a good reason for this being a bad idea?

Comment: "Strikes me this might be awesome." How's that? Idiomatic CoffeeScript won't match what a CoffeeScript to JavaScript translator will do, sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: Not sure I follow but I'll look into it. Sounds like that might be a good reason not to do it. Though I had the impression coffe-script converts seamlessly back and fourth.

Comment: You can seamlessly convert Fortran to C and back but what `f2c` produces will look nothing like what a C programmer would write. Similarly for *X to Y* for any languages *X* and *Y*.

Comment: oh ok, I see, it's s style issue, though I'd rather read  coffee-script any day of the week. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what the precise syntax would be, but if you have file-type specific autocommands enabled in vim, you should be able to hook the javascript -> coffee compiler to "execute just before buffer load". You should find information on that within vim, try "help autocmd". In there you should find something about "BufReadPre" and "FileReadPre", which should be just about right. Since you've already done it for write, you probably know the syntax to hook up the compiler to that autocmd better than I do from the top of my head.

Comment: I'll post an answer if I figure this out, though I'm not getting far with the buffer manipulation stuff.

Comment: The FileReadPre may be the better place to look, actually, but I can't say I know the subleties of buffers vs. files in vim.